# Need logic for printing table in php

Tags: php, logic

```
for ($count = 1; $count < 20; $count++) {
        if ($count == 1 || $count % 4 == 0) {
            ?> <tr> <?php 
        }
        if (true) {
            ?> <td><?php echo $count; ?></td> <?php
        }
        if (($count + 1) % 4 == 0){
            ?> </tr> <?php
        }
```

this code is running fine but only issue is its not printing new lines in good order after first 2 successful rows print, it exceeds the row by one more , m stuck, need the logic to make it correct. Thanks

Comment: what shell the result look like?

Comment: what kind of table do you want? how many rows/columns!!

Comment: Well rows are mentioned as < 20 and <td> are supposed to be 3 in every row! hope you got the idea .... its printing new row containing <td> but as I said I need 3 in one row, but its exceeding somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the rows, then iterate over the columns:

```
$counts = range(1, 19);
foreach (array_chunk($counts, 4) as $rowCounts)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($rowCounts as $count) 
    {
        printf("<td>%d</td>", $count);
    }
    echo '</tr>'; 
}
```

Comment: great, it worked just needed to change the 4 to 3.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Personally, what I do for very simple tables is something like:

```
function Tr ($text) {
    echo "<tr><td>$text</td></tr>";
}
```

And then you can loop like this:

```
for ($count = 1; $count < 20; $count++) {
    Tr ($count);
}
```

Also I'd advise you against switching in and out of  constantly like that, but I think that's just a matter of style.